# Catalan Definition Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, notation, catalan-numbers

I am currently taking discrete math 2, and we've just learned about Catalan Numbers.

In the formula given, the following was shown:
${2n \choose n}$

What does this mean, as far as these two numbers being in the same parenthesis together? I apologize, as I didn't really know what to ask, since I have no idea what this is called. Any help or pointing to resources would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The binomial coefficient $ {\binom mk}=\frac{m!}{k!(m-k)!}$, so $\binom{2n}n=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$

Comment: Another notation for those are $C^{2n}_n$ or $C_{2n,n}.$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the binomial coefficient. In general, 
[$$\binom nk = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!\,k!}.$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)
It is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^n$, as well as the number of ways of choosing $k$ out of $n$ objects, with repetition not allowed and order not important.

Answer (score 1):

The binomial coefficient $ {\binom mk}=\frac{m!}{k!(m-k)!}$, so $\binom{2n}n=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$